# Android Virtual Device closes immediately after opening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

My current problem is as soon as I try running ANY Android Virtual Device, it closes shortly after it starts. It never gets to a start screen, just black then closes.

I've tried switching from graphic mode auto to software.

I've tried creating a brand new AVD and wiping data of an older one.

I've ran android studios as admin, opened a admin cmd in windows and tried running the avd directly from the emulator exe (same results).

This is a brand new blank project from android studios.

I do NOT have docker installed, I also ensured VitrualBox is NOT running.

System:
windows 10, i7, discrete GPU.

This is the results of trying to run the virtual device with -verbose from cmd prompt.
I tried eliminating duplicate items.

```
emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_2
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir D:\andriodSDK\skins\
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2888: querying file version info API...
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2896: found kernelbase.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2904: GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2913: GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2943: VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2966: queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2888: querying file version info API...
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2966: queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:2888: querying file version info API...
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: autoconfig: -no-snapshot from AVD config.ini
emulator: Found 4 DNS servers: 192.168.5.1 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112 161.57.5.2
emulator: trying to load skin file 'D:\andriodSDK\skins\\pixel_2\layout'
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=v:* androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
emulator: Checking whether Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is available.
emulator: WinHvPlatform.dll found. Looking for WHvGetCapability...
emulator: WHvGetCapability found. Querying WHPX capabilities...
emulator: WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0

emulator: WHPX is either not available or not installed.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.5.4 (4) is installed and usable.
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:212:  no root specified: 
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:242: Found: 1 adb executables
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:244: Adb: D:\andriodSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:263: Path:D:\andriodSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: VERBOSE: emulator-qt-window.cpp:2826: setUIMultiDisplay id 0 0 0 1080 1920 add
emulator: Found 4 DNS servers: 192.168.5.1 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112 161.57.5.2
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.cpu.ncore = 4
  hw.ramSize = 2048
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = true
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.gyroscope = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
  test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
  test.monitorAdb = 0
  hw.lcd.width = 1080
  hw.lcd.height = 1920
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 420
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.lcd.vsync = 60
  hw.gltransport = pipe
  hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
  hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
  hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
  hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
  hw.fold.adjust = false
  hw.display1.width = 0
  hw.display1.height = 0
  hw.display1.density = 0
  hw.display1.xOffset = -1
  hw.display1.yOffset = -1
  hw.display1.flag = 0
  hw.display2.width = 0
  hw.display2.height = 0
  hw.display2.density = 0
  hw.display2.xOffset = -1
  hw.display2.yOffset = -1
  hw.display2.flag = 0
  hw.display3.width = 0
  hw.display3.height = 0
  hw.display3.density = 0
  hw.display3.xOffset = -1
  hw.display3.yOffset = -1
  hw.display3.flag = 0
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
  hw.camera.back = virtualscene
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 512
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  hw.arc = false
  hw.arc.autologin = false
  kernel.path = D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 3083m
  disk.vendorPartition.initPath = D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
  disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 800m
  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\encryptionkey.img
  PlayStore.enabled = false
  avd.name = Pixel_2_API_29
  avd.id = Pixel_2_API_29
  fastboot.forceColdBoot = true
  android.sdk.root = D:\andriodSDK
  android.avd.home = C:\Users\mike\.android\avd
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "192.168.5.1,9.9.9.9,149.112.112.112,161.57.5.2"
emulator: argv[03] = "-mem-path"
emulator: argv[04] = "C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\snapshots\default_boot\ram.img"
emulator: argv[05] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[06] = "null"
emulator: argv[07] = "-device"
emulator: argv[08] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin"
emulator: argv[09] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[10] = "android64"
emulator: argv[11] = "-enable-hax"
emulator: argv[12] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[13] = "cores=4"
emulator: argv[14] = "-m"
emulator: argv[15] = "2048"
emulator: argv[16] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[17] = "420"
emulator: argv[18] = "-nodefaults"
emulator: argv[19] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[20] = "D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64"
emulator: argv[21] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[22] = "D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,file=D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\system.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[31] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[32] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[35] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[36] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[39] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[40] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[41] = "-device"
emulator: argv[42] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[43] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[44] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[45] = "-device"
emulator: argv[46] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[47] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[48] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[49] = "-device"
emulator: argv[50] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[51] = "-device"
emulator: argv[52] = "virtio-rng-pci"
emulator: argv[53] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[54] = "-device"
emulator: argv[55] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1"
emulator: argv[56] = "-device"
emulator: argv[57] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2"
emulator: argv[58] = "-device"
emulator: argv[59] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3"
emulator: argv[60] = "-device"
emulator: argv[61] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4"
emulator: argv[62] = "-device"
emulator: argv[63] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5"
emulator: argv[64] = "-device"
emulator: argv[65] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6"
emulator: argv[66] = "-device"
emulator: argv[67] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7"
emulator: argv[68] = "-device"
emulator: argv[69] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8"
emulator: argv[70] = "-device"
emulator: argv[71] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9"
emulator: argv[72] = "-device"
emulator: argv[73] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10"
emulator: argv[74] = "-device"
emulator: argv[75] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11"
emulator: argv[76] = "-device"
emulator: argv[77] = "virtio-keyboard-pci"
emulator: argv[78] = "-L"
emulator: argv[79] = "D:\andriodSDK\emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[80] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[81] = "hda"
emulator: argv[82] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[83] = "none"
emulator: argv[84] = "-append"
emulator: argv[85] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR29X3X0X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=196609 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl cma=288M@0-4G ndns=4 qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=4352 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=bc84f7138eb2b5eeb318682e393649688bc3de8bf7151420a915a015e4bbfe4d androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m"
emulator: argv[86] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[87] = "C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -dns-server 192.168.5.1,9.9.9.9,149.112.112.112,161.57.5.2 -mem-path C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\snapshots\default_boot\ram.img -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-hax -smp cores=4 -m 2048 -lcd-density 420 -nodefaults -kernel D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64 -initrd D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11 -device virtio-keyboard-pci -L D:\andriodSDK\emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR29X3X0X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=196609 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl cma=288M@0-4G ndns=4 qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=4352 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=bc84f7138eb2b5eeb318682e393649688bc3de8bf7151420a915a015e4bbfe4d androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m" -android-hw C:\Users\mike\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd\hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Android qemu version 29.3.0.0 (build_id 6061023) (CL:N/A)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
Failed to open /usr/local/google/home/joshuaduong/emu/master/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196609'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '420'
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/New_York'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: emulator_window_fb_rotate

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: VERBOSE: winsys-qt.cpp:919: config multidisplay with config.ini 0x0 0x0 0x0

VCPU shutdown request
.....
.....
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
emulator: User-config was not changed.
emulator: Android emulator version 29.3.0.0 (build_id 6061023) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_2_API_29'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\

emulator: emuDirName: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\

emulator: Probing for D:\andriodSDK\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir D:\andriodSDK\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
emulator: Adding library search path: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: 'D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\qt\lib'
emulator: Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=D:\andriodSDK\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Quoted param: [D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe]
emulator: Quoted param: [-avd]
emulator: Quoted param: [Pixel_2_API_29]
emulator: Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: Running :D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_2_API_29"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 D:\andriodSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -verbose
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I have fixed the problem. One of the following items fixed it.
I did not do these one at a time, just all at once. So here is hoping this helps someone in the future.

Items I did that lead up to it being fixed.

1. uninstalled graphic driver + installed newest update
2. deleted .android folder (moved it to a new drive)
3. turned off gpu + reboot + turned back on gpu + reboot
4. deleted all AVD's and started a brand new one with a new device type and Android Q
5. cleared all Android Studios cache files

It now works fine with default AVD config

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the same effect as Solution(1) provided by hurnhu, I just:

(A) Select the Android Device from AVD

(B) Wipe-Data

(C) Cold-Boot

Without explicit deletion of any directories on Windows10 (AVD might have performed the deletion silently in the background).

Of course, by "Wipe-Data" you would lose all your apps deployed on that virtual device.